# Count character for textarea closest field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 4-5 textarea on my page and I have set the limitation of the character. The user can add 500 characters.

Now my issue is, I have to show the character count for the closest field. As of now, it's showing for all. I mean if I add any content in the first textarea then count showing for all textarea.

Please check the below image.

[image]

I was trying something like this

```
  current = $(this).closest('.row .valInfo').find('.currentchar'),
  maximum = $(this).closest('.valInfo').find('.maximumchar'),
  //theCount = $('.valInfo');
  theCount = $(this).closest('.valInfo')
```

```js
$('.characterCount').keyup(function() {
    var characterCount = $(this).val().length,
      current = $('.currentchar'),
      maximum = $('.maximumchar'),
      theCount = $('.valInfo');
    current.text(characterCount);
  }

);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <textarea maxlength="500" class="characterCount"></textarea>
    <div class="valInfo"><span class="currentchar">0</span> <span class="maximumchar">/ 500</span> Characters</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <textarea maxlength="500" class="characterCount"></textarea>
    <div class="valInfo"><span class="currentchar">0</span> <span class="maximumchar">/ 500</span> Characters</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can do that with data attributes and css after pseudo element. it will be more shorter

Comment: @MisterJojo, Can you share the example or any link where I can learn this?

Comment: ok, let me some minutes

Comment: sorry i was wrong, textarea elements cannot use pseudo elements. But it is possible to do this with a div using a content editable attribute

Comment: @MisterJojo, No issues, I think, In this scenario, the script is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the corresponding `currentchar`, `maximumchar` and `valinfo` elements relative to the element that has been edited. For example by only finding matching elements in the shared parent:

```js
$('.characterCount').keyup(function() {
    var elem = $(this),
      characterCount = elem.val().length;
      current = elem.parent().find('.currentchar'),
      maximum = elem.parent().find('.maximumchar'),
      theCount = elem.parent().find('.valInfo');
    current.text(characterCount);
  }

);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <textarea maxlength="500" class="characterCount"></textarea>
    <div class="valInfo"><span class="currentchar">0</span> <span class="maximumchar">/ 500</span> Characters</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <textarea maxlength="500" class="characterCount"></textarea>
    <div class="valInfo"><span class="currentchar">0</span> <span class="maximumchar">/ 500</span> Characters</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's working as expected. Thank you for the quick response. Upvote from my size.